# Display a Hyperlink in alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there any method possible to display a hyperlink like "read more" in Alexa skill?
I am trying to display a hyperlink in my custom Alexa skill but could not find any method to implement it

Comment: Do you mean when sending a card as part of your response? If so, no. That isn't possible. https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/include-a-card-in-your-skills-response.html

Answer (score 4):

Hyperlinks are now available as part of an [APL](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-overview.html) directive for devices that support it. You can read the documentation [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-standard-commands.html#open_url_command):

> **OpenURL Command**
>
> The OpenURL command, if successful, opens the specified URL in a web
>   browser or other application on the device. You must provide a
>   suitable URL that works on the current device.

They give an example:

```
{
  "type": "OpenURL",
  "source": "https://www.amazon.com/",
  "onFail": {
    "type": "SetValue",
    "componentId": "errorText",
    "property": "text",
    "value": "Unable to open Amazon.com (${event.source.value})"
  }
}
```

Description about supported devices:

> Not all devices support opening a URL. If the device does not support
>   opening URLs, the command is ignored and it does not run onFail
>   commands. Check the value of the allowOpenURL in the data-binding
>   context to determine if OpenURL is supported on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my skill but all I get is a blank (black) page.
Normally the Silk browser on Echo Show device can properly display the page I tried.

I used the following APL document to test:

```
{
  "type": "APL",
  "version": "1.9",
  "description": "A hello world APL document.",
  "theme": "dark",
  "mainTemplate": {
    "parameters": [
      "payload"
    ],
    "items": [
      {
          "type": "OpenURL",
          "source": "http://192.168.254.240/",
          "onFail": {
            "type": "SetValue",
            "componentId": "errorText",
            "property": "text",
            "value": "Unable to open (${event.source.value})"
          }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

so what is wrong ?

I found the correct usage (or a workaround):

```
{
    "type": "APL",
    "version": "1.8",
    "theme": "dark",
    "import": [
        {
            "name": "alexa-layouts",
            "version": "1.5.0"
        }
    ],
"mainTemplate": {
    "parameters": [
        "payload"
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "Pager",
            "id": "fisrtpager",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%",
            "items": [
            ],
            "navigation": "none",
            "onMount": [{
  "type": "OpenURL",
  "source": "http://192.168.254.240/",
  "onFail": {
    "type": "SetValue",
    "componentId": "errorText",
    "property": "text",
    "value": "Unable to open Amazon.com (${event.source.value})"
  }
            }]
        }
    ]
}
}
```